# Is there an inverse for surface tension?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, fluid-statics, liquid-state

While I was trying to understand surface tension, I [read in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension) that,

> surface tension results from the greater attraction of liquid molecules to each other (due to cohesion) than to the molecules in the air (due to adhesion).

And we have seen this in case of liquid-air interface. I wonder whether there is a combination of some liquid & gas in which cohesion (attraction) force in-between liquid molecules are less than gas-liquid molecule attraction via adhesive forces. What happens there?. Will there be an inverse phenomenon?

Comment: If this is the case, then the gas phase would be favored. Liquids and solids have a positive surface tension; gases do not.

Comment: An example of inverse phenomena would be [hydrophilicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophile).